# find some text aa and then find first appearance of text bb after aa

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

The whole text file is like below:

```
aa
...
bb
...
bb
...
aa
...
bb
...
```

After line `aa` there will be one or more lines of `bb`.

I tried the command below which will fine all lines `aa` and the line above `aa`.

```
grep -A 1 aa fileName
```

How can I print out all lines `aa` and the line above `aa` also the first line `bb` after line `aa` and the line above this `bb` line?

edited: need to find first(and only the first) line `bb` for each occurrence of `aa`, also print out line number. maybe I re-phrase the question: for each line `aa`, find the first line `bb` after this `aa`, then print out both line `aa`, `bb` and the line above them, with line number as well.

consider below input file, the first column is the line number, it is not part of the input file

```
1 xxx
2 aa
3 xxxx
4 bb
5 bb
6 xxxx
7 aa
8 xxxx
9 xxxx
10 xxxx
11 bb
12 xxx
13 aa
14 xxx
15 bb
```

I want output:

```
1 xxx
2 aa
3 xxxx
4 bb
6 xxxx
7 aa
10 xxxx
11 bb
12 xxx
13 aa
14 xxx
15 bb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
awk '/aa/{f=1}/aa|bb/&&f{printf "%d %s\n%d %s\n",NR-1,a,NR,$0}{a=$0}/bb/{f=0}'
```

Comment: Thanks! somehow the first one didn't work for me, i can deal with it using grep. The second one is only showing the first occurrence, how can it show all such occurrence? and also output the line number?

Comment: If you can deal with the first with `grep` then why ask the question, as for the second, yes it quits after the first match because that is what you asked for, print the line number is easy. I have made the edits.

Comment: I edited the question clarify the question again. For each line of `aa`, find the first and only the first line of `bb` after this `aa`. There could be multiple lines(at least one) of `bb` between two `aa` line, I only need to find the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
grep -C 1 aa fileName
```

would print all lines with aa and the line before and after

Comment: Thanks. I knew -A, -B and -C option for grep, but this doesn't answer my question(find first occurrence of bb after aa).